# js if else result as condition in another if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm wondering if it is possible to use in javascript the result of one if/else statement as condition for another if/else statement. Let me visualize this idea with the code:

```
if ( if (thatstrue) { return true } else { return false } ) {
 do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can use ternary operator if statement as condition that way:

```js
a = true;

ifFunction = function() {
  if ( true && a ? true : false) {
  console.log('a is true');
  } else {
  console.log('a is false');
  }
}

ifFunction();

a= false;

ifFunction();
```

I'm giving this Q&A style post becouse i had this problem today in a much more complicated situation with connection with other conditions and couldn't search for a simple and direct answer anywhere. I found a solution by myself hardly reminding myself one line ternary operator and trying to use it. I found it working! Begginners in js mostly use classic if/else conditional blocks (which You can't use that way) and are not familiar with the ternary if/else statement way, which You can simply use as condition in other if else statement. I hope i will help some noob coders like me ;) If i did than please vote me up :D

Comment: `if (a) {` is easier to read.

Comment: @Andy - of course! This simple example is only for understanding the idea and not using it that way ;) In my case using this idea helped me to save many lines of code so i could compare some other conditions with the result of if/else, using only one line and one condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to always do this is to abstract the first condition to a function. You can even use it to take parameters and add additional logic iif you need to expand the use case.

```js
var a = 'foobar'

function checkForSomeACondition() {
  return a === myTrueCondition
}


// ...then 

if (checkForSomeACondition()){
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: You know, If u have hundred of other functions already in your code hard to scroll and need another one only to run it once, than You are trying to write it simpler way. :) 

I'm not saying it's the only way u can achieve the same result. U re right, that You can use a function as an condiotion. But i think some people will be searching for a simple answer: "can i use if/else as condition in another if/else" and i hope they will find my Q&A. Finally - thanks a lot for Your comment - i think it will be also helpfull, giving noobs some other ideas of coding ;)